# Parse a list line by line, create a new list in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to read in a file that contains lines of source/destination IPs and ports as well as a tag. I'm using Get-Content:

```
Get-Content $logFile -ReadCount 1 | % {

} | sort | get-unique | Out-File "C:\Log\logout.txt"
```

This is an example of the input file:

```
|10.0.0.99|345|195.168.4.82|58164|spam|
|10.0.0.99|345|195.168.4.82|58164|robot|
|10.0.0.99|231|195.168.4.82|58162|spam|
|195.168.4.82|58162|10.0.0.99|231|robot|
|10.0.0.99|345|195.168.4.82|58168|spam|
|10.0.0.99|345|195.168.4.82|58169|spam|
```

What I need to do is output a new list, but if the same source/destination IPs/ports are both 'spam' and 'robot' I just need to output that line as 'robot' (lines 1 and 2 above). 
I need to do the same if the reverse direction of an existing connection is either 'spam' or 'robot', I just need one or the other and it would be 'robot' (lines 3 and 4 above). There will be plenty of 'spam' lines without a duplicate or reverse connection (the last couple lines above), they need to just stay the same.

This is what i've been using to create the reverse direction of the connection, but I haven't been able to figure out how to properly create the new list:

```
$reverse = '|' + ($_.Split("|")[3,4,1,2,5] -join '|') + '|'
```

Output of the above would be:

```
|10.0.0.99|345|195.168.4.82|58164|robot|
|195.168.4.82|58162|10.0.0.99|231|robot|
|10.0.0.99|345|195.168.4.82|58168|spam|
|10.0.0.99|345|195.168.4.82|58169|spam|
```

(except that second line didn't have to be the reversed direction)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use `Import-Csv input.csv -Delimiter '|' -Headers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7` for importing the file, then you can filter by `Sort-Object -Unique 6`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Nitpicking ;-) It's singular `-Header` and `Sort-Object -Unique '5'`

Comment: Indeed it is. Note to self: don't comment while doing other stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since both direct and reverse connections are checked and their line order may not  be sequential, I would use a hashtable to store the type of both directions and do everything algorithmically:

```
$checkPoints = @{}
$output = [ordered]@{}
$reader = [IO.StreamReader]'R:\1.txt'
while (!$reader.EndOfStream) {
    $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    $s = $line.split('|')
    $direct = [string]::Join('|', $s[1..4])
    $reverse = [string]::Join('|', ($s[3,4,1,2]))
    $type = $s[5]
    $known = $checkPoints[$direct]
    if (!$known -or ($type -eq 'robot' -and $known -eq 'spam')) {
        $checkPoints[$direct] = $checkPoints[$reverse] = $type
        $output[$direct] = $line
        $output.Remove($reverse)
    } elseif ($type -eq 'spam' -and $known -eq 'robot') {
        $output.Remove($reverse)
    }
}
$reader.Close()
Set-Content r:\2.txt -Encoding utf8 -value @($output.Values)
```

Comment: Nice solution +1, congrats to the 20k.

Comment: @wOxxOm, this is much appreciated! I have noticed that when a 'spam' identical line comes after a 'robot' line, nothing is being sent to output `|64.12.235.58|80|195.168.2.214|1979|robot|
|64.12.235.58|80|195.168.2.214|1979|spam|`  Otherwise, it works very nicely!

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you again; I am getting 'Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null' error though...

Comment: If the input file may have empty lines then you should add a check: `$s = $line.split('|'); if ($s.count -ne 7) { continue }`

Comment: @wOxxOm, yikes; this time I simply changed `$direct` to `$reverse` instead of copy/pasting and it works like a charm. I must have fumbled something  up before. Thank you very much!